# Tab page fragment not visible on application start

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I have tab fragment implemented, it uses:

```
Fragment fragment = currentTab.getFragment();
FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tabId);
transaction.commit();
```

When the application starts the tabs headers are visible, but content (child fragment) of that tab page is not. Then when I click on another tab, the content of the first tab blinks on the screen, but being replaced by the content of the second tab. When I click back to first tab, it works correctly now (content is visible), and also all other tabs are OK.

Structure:

```
TabFragment
 |
 |- TabPageFragment1
 |  |
 |  |- FilterFragment
 |  \- ListFragment
 |
 |- TabPageFragment2 (also contains filter/list fragments)
 \- TabPageFragment3 (^)
```

It seems like the child fragment is postponed and not somehow shown. Its view is created. I've tried adding show/attach to the transaction to no avail. I also tried to force the transaction to execute:

```
manager.executePendingTransactions()
```

But that throws exception:

```
Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

What should I do so the tab page fragment is shown when application starts? It's obviously working when I click tab to next, and back. Why is it not there first time?

Comment: As no one even tried. I converted the solution to android.support.v4 version, and it works much better.